# PyQt5: Get GL parameters from QtOpenGLWidget without showing first

Tags: python, opengl, qt5, pyqt5

Is it possible to use GL functions like `glGetString` without showing the widget first?

The basic use case would be taking this [helloworld](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/opengl/hellogl.py) and instead of showing the widget, maybe I want to print a command line usage message with the GPU information and GL version. The script currently does this already after showing the widget.

In my own application I have a subclass of a `QOpenGLWidget` and I've tried manually creating a `QOpenGLContext`, setting the format, and making it current (with and without `.create()`), but that didn't seem to work. The subclass seems to work fine when shown.

Any help is much appreciated.

Further details: I'm one of the maintainers of the python library vispy and I'm trying to update our PyQt5 backend to use `QOpenGLWidget` instead of `QGLWidget`. The pull request is here if anyone wants to tell us what we're doing wrong: https://github.com/vispy/vispy/pull/1394

Answer (score 0):

A OpenGL context needs a "window" (exactly needs a "Device Contex" or a "Display", depending on the OS) to render to. That window doesn't need to be visible, just that the gl context is current to it.

The easiest way is to `hide()` (or don't call `show()`) the window at its creation. You can make it visible later.